Does cardinality still make sense under an illfounded context?
As title states, I'm curious whether the concept of every set having an associated cardinality (under $\mathsf{ZFC}$, of course) still makes sense or breaks down somewhere when one allows for illfounded sets (loops, cycles, infinite downward chains, etc.).
Intuitively, I don't believe it should, as even a set like $\Omega$ (defined by $\Omega = \{\Omega\}$) still really only has $1$ element (itself) and whichever downward chain may be found in said element is not of any concern for the association $1 \to \Omega$. But maybe some issues arise with regard to the required transitivity/wellfoundedness in association with some ordinals?

No, no problem, bijections still work, ordinals still work. However, if we drop choice as well as foundation, there is in general no way to define cardinal numbers (i.e. a class function $F:V\to V$ such that $F(x)=F(y)$ if and only if there is a bijection $x\to y$), though there can be a way to recover this under certain antifoundation axioms.

@spaceisdarkgreen Thank you for the quick and helpful answer!

I should say, the notion of equipotence (i.e. "there is a bijection between $x$ and $y$") doesn't require foundation or choice in any way... so in that sense "cardinality" makes sense for very weak set theories. The question of whether there are "cardinals" (i.e. defined set representatives of the classes of said equivalence relation) is the more delicate one I was addressing there.

And while I guess "is a Quine atom infinite" might invite some legitimate philosophical discussion, the answer according to the standard definitions is straightforwardly "no, it has cardinality $1$".
